# How to get an existing EKS cluster's OIDCProvider using CDK?

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-cdk

I have an existing EKS cluster (Created by a separate CF stack) and I want to extract the OIDCProviderURL associated with that cluster using CDK.

Here's my snippet of code

```
const k8sCluster = <eks.Cluster>(eks.Cluster.fromClusterAttributes(this, "k8scluster", {
      clusterName: "k8s-sample"
    }))
const oidcprovider = k8sCluster.clusterOpenIdConnectIssuerUrl
```

When I execute *cdk synth* the oidcprovider value is **undefined**. The documentation for *Cluster.fromClusterAttributes* mentions that the output would be "undefined" if the cluster is not *kubectl-enabled*. I am not sure what is meant by *kubectl-enabled*. Can anyone let me know how I can get the k8s cluster's OIDC provider using CDK.

Answer (score -2):

I have a very simple cluster definition [here](https://github.com/quixoticmonk/cdk-eks/blob/main/eks/eks_stack.py) . CFN returns the oidc issue url for the cluster with both the output values I have defined there.

```
    cdk.CfnOutput(
        self,
        "oidcendpointurl",
        value=_cluster.cluster_open_id_connect_issuer_url
    )

    cdk.CfnOutput(
        self,
        "oidcendpoint",
        value=_cluster.cluster_open_id_connect_issuer
    )
```

[image]